# Waiting for a WaitGroup and ranging over a channel results in a "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"

Tags: go

I launch goroutines from the main func, waiting for all to finish using a `WaitGroup`. Each goroutine also emits data to a channel, and I iterate the values in my main func:

```
func main() {
  wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
  c := make(chan io.ReadWriteCloser)
  ports := getPortName()

  for _, port range ports {
    wg.Add(1)
    go connectToPort(serial.OpenOptions{
      PortName: port,
    }, wg, &c)
  }

  wg.Wait()
  for conn := range c {
    fmt.Print(conn)
  }
}

func connectToPort(options serial.OpenOptions, wg *sync.WaitGroup, c *chan io.ReadWriteCloser) {
  defer wg.Done()

  connection := serial.Connect(options)

  *c <- connection
  
}
```

This results in:

```
Fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You never read from the channel until all of the goroutines exit, and you never write to the channel until you read from it. Thus a deadlock.

Comment: Also note there's no reason to pass a pointer to a channel. Change `c *chan io.ReadWriteCloser` to simply `c chan io.ReadWriteCloser`.  Or better yet:  `c chan<- io.ReadWriteCloser`, to only pass the writeable end of the channel.

Comment: @Flimzy Then how can i both wait for the goroutines and read from the channel? I just started with go 2 weeks ago so its still new

Comment: Don't wait to start reading. Put your `for` loop that reads in a separate goroutine that doesn't wait.

Comment: I thought it would make sure that all the goroutines have passed data to the channel and then i could iterate the values

Comment: Bacause without ```Wait()``` the program exists, and sometimes it doesnt print all the connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the deadlock?

This line:

```
  wg.Wait()
```

waits for the waitgroup to complete, before it starts reading from the channel, yet this line

```
  *c <- connection
```

Doesn't write to the channel until the channel can be read (since you're using an unbuffered channel). So you have an obvious deadlock situation.

The simplest solution is to read from the channel before the writing is complete. Do this with a separate goroutine, for example:

```
  go func() {
    for conn := range c {
      fmt.Print(conn)
    }
  }()
  wg.Wait() // Now wait for the goroutines to complete before exiting the program.
```

But this can be further improved by eliminating the waitgroup entirely. Since you know how many results to expect, the waitgroup is completely unnecessary:

```
func main() {
  c := make(chan io.ReadWriteCloser)
  ports := getPortName()

  for _, port range ports {
    go connectToPort(serial.OpenOptions{
      PortName: port,
    }, c)
  }

  for i := 0; i < len(ports); i ++ {
    conn := <-c
    fmt.Print(conn)
  }
}

func connectToPort(options serial.OpenOptions, c chan<- io.ReadWriteCloser) {
  c <- serial.Connect(options)
}
```

Note in the above code I've made two additional improvements:

1. I stopped using a pointer to a channel. This is unnecessary complexity.
2. I've also modified `connectToPort` to accept a `chan<-` type, which means it cannot read from the channel.

Answer (score -1):

To make sure you read all the values from the `c` channel and don't produce a deadlock, separate the closing of the `c` channel and `wg.Wait()` into a separate goroutine.

```
func main() {
  wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
  c := make(chan io.ReadWriteCloser)
  ports := getPortName()
  for _, port := range ports {
    wg.Add(1)
    go connectToPort(serial.OpenOptions{
      PortName: port,
    }, wg, &c)
  }

  go func (wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan io.ReadWriteCloser) {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
  }(&wg, c)
 
  for conn := range c {
    fmt.Print(conn)
  }
}
```

This way, by reading from the `c` channel in the main goroutine, you will make sure that all values are read before program exits.

Comment: 1. This actually doesn't guarantee that the channel is closed before exit, since the exit could occur before the new goroutine wakes or finishes execution.  The only way to guarantee that is to put the `wg.Wait()` and `close()` calls directly in the same goroutine that controls the exit. 2. Closing the channel before exit is completely unnecessary anyway, since exiting, pretty much by definition, closes all channels and clears up all other resources.

Comment: How can exit occur if ranging over the channel is blocking the main goroutine?

Comment: That is what I'm asking. If `for conn := range c` blocks the program from exiting, in which case the program exits before `close(ch)` happens?

Comment: I'm not able to see your example, but it doesn't matter. In my code example, `for conn := range c` reads the values from the channel. It also blocks the `main` method from finishing, until the channel is closed. My question for you is, in which case, looking at my code example, `close(ch)` will never execute, if it's responsible for closing the channel that in blocking the `main` method from finishing the execution?

Comment: I feel like we misunderstood each other at some point. I never said that the goroutine with `wg.Wait()` and `close(ch)` will block anything. The `main` goroutine (the main func) is blocked with ranging over the channel `c` (`for conn := range c`) after all values are read from the channel, until channel `c` is closed.

Comment: My question was regarding your first point (1.) in the first comment. I don't agree that the only way this executes correctly is to put `wg.Wait` and `close` in the same goroutine that controls the exit. My question was is there any case when the code in my example executes incorrectly (I don't believe so, but I could be wrong). To illustrate my point, I've modified your example and added another printout: https://play.golang.org/p/bRfWj_txvsD . `main done` is always printed out after `channel closed`, as that is when the main goroutine is unblocked and finishes with execution.

Comment: What is the case when `close` may never be called? My example executes `close(ch)`, then prints out `channel closed`, then exits the `for conn := range c` loop, prints out `main done`, then exits the program.

Your example works in the same way. After `close(ch)` is executed and `channel closed` is printed out, the program exits. No matter how big the timeout is,  for me it always executes in this order. I would just like to know if there is a case when `close` does not get executed in these examples.

Comment: Please accept my apologies. I was mistaken about my analysis.

Comment: no worries, it happens :) . I do agree that `sync.Waitgroup` in this particular solution is an overkill, but it does work :) .